# How to play a simple audio file with Xamarin iOS/Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, audio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to learn and play a bit with Xamarin :)
I wanted to play a simple sound at the end of a certain time and in part I succeeded, this works on the android and ios emulators but when I try to build the app on my iPhone this crush at the moment of sound reproduction!

the code I wrote I copied from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/playing-audio-mp3-file-in-xamarin-forms/)!

so my code is this:

iAudio.cs :

```
using System;
namespace StopWatch
{
    public interface IAudio
    {
        void PlayAudioFile(string fileName);
    }
}
```

AudioService.cs in Android :

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using StopWatch.Droid;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Content.Res;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioService))]
namespace StopWatch.Droid
{
    public class AudioService : IAudio
    {
        public AudioService()
        { }
        public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName)
        {
            var player = new MediaPlayer();
            var fd = global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd(fileName);
            player.Prepared += (s, e) =>
            {
                player.Start();
            };
            player.SetDataSource(fd.FileDescriptor, fd.StartOffset, fd.Length);
            player.Prepare();
        }
    }
}
```

AudioService.cs in iOS:

```
using System; using Xamarin.Forms; using StopWatch; using StopWatch.iOS; using System.IO; using Foundation; using AVFoundation; [assembly: Dependency(typeof(AudioService))] namespace StopWatch.iOS {
    public class AudioService : IAudio
    {
        public AudioService()
        { }
        public void PlayAudioFile(string fileName)
        {
            string sFilePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName), Path.GetExtension(fileName));
            NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString(sFilePath);
            var _player = AVAudioPlayer.FromUrl(url);
            _player.FinishedPlaying += (object sender, AVStatusEventArgs e) =>
            {
                _player = null;
            };
            _player.Play();
        }
    } 
}
```

and this is mi MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace StopWatch
{
    // Learn more about making custom code visible in the Xamarin.Forms previewer
    // by visiting https://aka.ms/xamarinforms-previewer
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch;
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            lblStopWatch.Text = "00:00:00";
            lblStopWatchAllert.Text = "";
        }

        private void btnStartClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10), () =>
            {
                lblStopWatch.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString().Substring(0, 8);
                controll(lblStopWatch.Text);
                return true;

            });
        }

        private void btnStopClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
        }

        private void btnResetClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
        }

        private void controll(String time)
        {
            if (string.Compare(time, "00:00:03:0000") > 0)
            {

                stopwatch.Reset();
                lblStopWatchAllert.Text = "time is over!";

                DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("Alert.mp3");

            }
        }

    }
}
```

the code crashes me at this point of the iOS AudioService.cs file:
[image]

I think the problem lies in the info.plist (although I am most likely wrong) but I don't know how to solve it :(
can someone help me? thank you

Comment: Hi ,could you show where the audio file in Xamarin iOS folder . It should be added in `Resources` folder in iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked this code , it works in my site . Invoking the play method as follow :

```
DependencyService.Get<IAudio>().PlayAudioFile("Alan_Walker.mp3");
```

The other codes are the same with yours in iOS and Android , they all play the sound successfully.

Here you need to notice that ,the local sound file should be added to each platform .And each platform has its specical folder to put the auido file .

In **Android** , you need to put it in `Assets` folder as follow :

[image]

And in **iOS** , you need to put it in Resources folder as follow :

[image]

==========================Update===================================

You should first add file to this folder as follow :

[image]

Then add **Existing** file to this folder :

[image]

Then when installing app , this filw will be added to mobile . No matter what is a simulator or a physical device.

**Note** :

Not copying file from other path to Xamarin.iOS project , this can't make sure the file be added to the project .

Comment: I had already done this, in fact if I try the code on the emulators it works correctly.
This ArgumentNullExeption problem only happens when I try to build on my iPhone.
For this reason "I think" is some problem related to permissions and I do not copy the audio file on the device when i build.
Could it be something related to info.plist or itunes?
Thanks

Comment: @CharlieLomello Hi , I also tested in a physical device  ,it also works .And I not adding anything in `info.plist` . By the way , maybe you not put the audio file in the Xamarin.iOS . Not copying file name to `Resources` , you need to add file in the folder first , then add existing file to this folder . I will explain it in answer . If just copy name to folder , the path of file is also in pc .When installing app in physical device , the file can not be added in Mobile .

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the last step, now it work perfectly :D